# egrep command for lines that have one or more instance of 1234 but no other numbers?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

So I'm fairly new to regular expressions and I'm wondering how this would be implemented as a egrep command.

I basically want to look for lines in a file that have one or more instances of "1234", but no other numbers. (non-digit characters are allowed).

Examples:

1234 - valid

12341234 - valid

12345 - invalid (since 5 is there)

Comment: What you ask seems very broad. Could you show us a *real* example and what you are really trying to do?

Comment: I'm essentially just trying to see how you can manipulate a regex to just look for lines that have the same repeated string over and over, with nothing else EXCEPT that string...

Comment: And what do you mean by "no other numbers"? Is the string `1234sdflksjdflsdjkfl1234` a valid string?

Comment: i apologize, i should have been more clear. Yes that string is valid (as long as the other characters are non-digit characters).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` to extract the lines that contain `1234`, then replace `1234` with something that doesn't appear in the input, then remove lines that still contain any digits, and replace the special string back by `1234`:

```
< input-file grep 1234 \
    | sed 's/1234/\x1/g' \
    | grep -v '[0-9]' \
    | sed 's/\x1/1234/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

So, we want to select lines that have 1234 one or more times but no other digits:

```
grep -E '^([^[:digit:]]*1234)+[^[:digit:]]*$' file
```

#### How it works

The regex begins with `^` and ends with `$`.  That means that is must match the whole line.

Inside the regex are two parts:

1. `([^[:digit:]]*1234)+` matches one or more `1234` with no other digits.
2. `[^[:digit:]]*` matches any non-digits that follows the last `1234`.

In olden times, one would use `[0-9]` to match digits.  With unicode, that is no longer reliable.  So, we are using `[:digit:]` which is unicode safe.

#### Example

Let's use this test file:

```
$ cat file
this 1234 is valid
12341234 valid
not valid 12345
not 2 valid 1234 line
no numbers so not valid
```

Here is the result:

```
$ grep -E '^([^[:digit:]]*1234)+[^[:digit:]]*$' file
this 1234 is valid
12341234 valid
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want no other digit after your 1234 block:

```
egrep '\<(1234)+(\>|[^0-9])' *

       --        --                --> word delimiters
          ----                     --> the word you're looking for
                    ------         --> non digit characters
               -                   --> one or more times
```

If you want only "words" made up by the "1234" block, then you can egrep this:

```
egrep '\<(1234)+\>' *

       --       --  --> word delimiters
          ----      --> the word you're looking for
               -    --> one or more times.
```